# Docker compose errror when mounting the volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In order to see changes in your working directory inside docker, as far as I understand on the `docker-compose.yml` you need to map the volume to the directory you are going to work.

currently I have this

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
   - .:/data/app
```

Therefore I'm mapping my machine directory `.` to the container on the `data/app` folder, but if I do this I get this error:

```
ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"bin/develop.sh\": stat bin/develop.sh: no such file or directory"
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

If I don't set the `volumes` tag the container actually boots and all but any change I made into the directory is not transfer to the container.

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "8080:8080"
```

*NOTE:* this exact same configuration works on my coworkers machines, the server, and even on my mac, the only one giving issues with the `volumes` is my ubuntu machine and don't understand why.

Docker versions runing on `Ubuntu 16.10`:

```
Docker version 17.04.0-ce, build 4845c56
docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245
```

**UPDATE**

for `CMD` I have this `./bin/start.sh` which contains

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/usr/bin/supervisord -c ./config/supervisord.conf
```

In the Docker file I have this

```
ENV APP_DIR /data/app/
WORKDIR $APP_DIR
```

And the working directory inside the container is: `/data/app`.

Comment: Can you show your CMD and the Workdir of the image?

Comment: hi @Robert just updated the post hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to replace `.` with the full path you want to mount into your container.

It may also be worth building an image with your start script included in your image (or, if your script will remain the same as you show in your question, just run supervisord as your `CMD`, without using the script).

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when something in your Dockerfile creates a `bin/develop.sh` that doesn't exist in your host directory. The other possibility is the script on your host may have windows linefeeds, and so `/bin/sh` instead looks for `/bin/sh<cr>` and the later file does not exist.